# What was Melanie Cole's fantasy?

Tags: fantasy-island

Possible spoilers ahead to the 2020 release Fantasy Island...

So at the start we see Melanie gets her fantasy of torturing her high school bully. Then

> as the movie progresses the truth is revealed and we learn that Melanie's real fantasy was to get revenge on those that ruined her date with Nick. But if that is true then how does her high school bully Sloane fit into everything and get pulled into it all? It seems that Melanie cheated the system and got two fantasies, right?

I can't think of a possible connection for those two characters... am i missing something?